# How may I create a large annotated Corpus for training?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, natural-language, supervised-learning

I am trying to create an annotated corpus of few million words. I want to use it as training data for some supervised algorithm. I may try to implement a task like Parts of Speech(PoS) Tagging or Name Entity Recognition(NER). Labeling the data by hand may be a mammoth task. I was thinking to write a simple code keeping a dictionary at back end. Is it fine? Or is there a faster approach? Please suggest if any one may. If it is a cross posting my apology for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative to annotating a new corpus by hand is to try and get an already annotated corpus. There are many corpora available (with different annotation layers, metadata, languages, registers, annotation quality, and licence conditions).

Comment: That is a good solution, but if I need to learn how to do it? I may use for novel tagsets also.

Comment: There seems some good papers. Crowdsourcing may be a good option. I am working out a fast alternative.